# get array of a product's assigned/used attributes?

Tags: attributes, catalog, code

what is the easiest way to start from a product instance and get a list of the attributes both standard and custom, set for that particular product ?
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, the easiest way is using `$product->getData();`